# Magento 2 - Paypal duplicate orders issue fix

Tags: magento, magento2

I've been searching for a fix to the following [bug in magento 2](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14592)

[This solution](https://skynix.co/resources/duplicated-paypal-orders-in-magento-2-free-fix) seems to be promising. However, I'm not sure how to install this fix after looking at the [github repository](https://github.com/skynixukraine/Magento-2-Duplicated-Paypal-Orders).

I've tried getting in touch with the developers without much success. I think this may just be an extension but I'm not really sure. If anyone could provide point me at a relevant tutorial on how to install it, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install the extension:

First, create a directory `<your_magento_dir>/app/code/Skynix/PaypalDuplicatedOrders` and copy the files from Github into that directory

Then use following commands in CLI:

1. bin/magento module:enable Skynix_PaypalDuplicateOrders
2. bin/magento setup:upgrade
3. bin/magento setup:di:compile
4. bin/magento cache:flush

That should do the trick.